# Woocommerce - Two dependent variation attributes

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have two variation attributes that are dependent one to another. One is called Surface, and allows the customer to choose among 6 different surface types. The second is called Color, and allows the customer to choose among a various number of colors (different number and different colors) for each surface.

So, the first surface type has 10 different colors, the second surface has 5 colors (different from the first), the third has 9 colors (different from the other two), the fourth has 12 different colors (again different from all previous), and fifth and sixth have 7 colors each (again different from the others and from each other).

So in the Surface attribute I created all 6 terms (types of surfaces), and in the Color attribute I created again all terms (different colors).

Also, each Surface has its own price, which is the same for all colors of that surface type...

So in order to avoid creating 50 different variations, I'd like to create just 6, one for each Surface, and for the Color I'd like to choose the option Any color. But at the same time, I'd like to be able to limit the available colors for surface to only the applicable ones.

Would this be possible somehow? TIA.